# Stored procedure taking a long time to update SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have create a stored procedure to perform bulk updates. When updating data, it takes nearly 15 minutes to update 1.5k rows. I running it from C#.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BulkUpdate_Lock_Details
    @BulkUpdate_Lock_Details tblType_Lock_Details READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE p 
    SET LockStatus = t.LockStatus, 
        UserName = t.UserName, 
        LockTimeStamp = t.LockTimeStamp 
    FROM Lock_Details p
    INNER JOIN @BulkUpdate_Lock_Details t ON p.FileName = t.FileName

    INSERT INTO Lock_Details (FileName, LockStatus, UserName, LockTimeStamp)
        SELECT t.FileName, t.LockStatus, t.UserName, t.LockTimeStamp
        FROM @BulkUpdate_Lock_Details t
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Lock_Details p 
                          WHERE p.FileName = t.FileName)
END
```

C# code will look like below,The datatable has the updated information

```
using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("BulkUpdate_Lock_Details", sqlConnection))
{
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BulkUpdateTableType_Lock_Details", dataTable);

    sqlConnection.Open();
    int res = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

I tried created a stored procedure and which is taking very long time to updated,tried merge option that was creating some other problem.

Since I don't have much background in SQL, I am unable to look for a better solution.

Comment: Can you post details of any indexes on the underlying table and the user defined table type? Or better yet, [retrieve the execution plan from the plan cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-cached-plans-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and post that?

Comment: Please also include the schema definition for the table, its indexes and the table type. You are passing 1.5k rows to the SP?

Comment: I assume you are running the Stored Procedure using SQL Server Management Studio and it is taking 15 minutes.  So the issue is in the Server and not in the c# code.  For code to run quickly on the SSMS the MDF file must be attached to the database and NOT a Local DB.  Speed of a query will depend on the speed of the microprocessor, the amount of RAM on the machine, the number of Cores in the processor.  Queries can take a long time if the database is fragmented or size get to be very large.  SQL Express has limits that are intentional so users will pay for Full Release version.

Comment: Activity Monitor is a really simple tool

Comment: to search and find slow query/sp.

Comment: Check Recent Expensive Query sect with Activity Monitor

Comment: Regarding off-hand suggestions to use `MERGE` (which you already said you tried anyway), it doesn't solve the problem on its own, and brings others; see [So, you want to use MERGE, eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge) And for this pattern, see [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) for the right transaction and locking syntax. For the actual symptom you are experiencing, well, I don't think the operation is taking a long time, I suspect you are blocked. Check `sys.dm_exec_requests` while it is "taking a long time."

Comment: Check to see if you have an index defined on `Lock_Details(FileName)`. If not, I recommend you create one to see if that improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

Table variables does not perform fast in queries because the optimizer that use statistics to find the good execution plan for the query does not have statistics on dynamic structures (a table variable is not a persistant object).

In some recent version of SQL Server (2019, 2022) the optimizer can stop the query and try to have statistics on such objects, then, continue the query...

Without statistics, the optimizer will put an arbitrary number of rows for statistics that can be dramatic to choose some algorithms for the execution plan, particularly join algorithms...

To avoid this situation, you have many solutions, that relies on the same concept, having statistics before executing the final queries...

As an exemple, I will do this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BulkUpdate_Lock_Details
    @BulkUpdate_Lock_Details tblType_Lock_Details READONLY
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #BulkUpdate_Lock_Details
   ("FileName"      VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
    LockStatus      VARCHAR(16)
    UserName        NVARCHAR(128)
    LockTimeStamp   DATETIME2);

INSERT INTO #BulkUpdate_Lock_Details
   SELECT * FROM @BulkUpdate_Lock_Details;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX X_#BulkUpdate_Lock_Details 
   ON ##BulkUpdate_Lock_Details ("FileName");

UPDATE p 
SET    LockStatus = t.LockStatus, 
       UserName = t.UserName, 
       LockTimeStamp = t.LockTimeStamp 
FROM   Lock_Details p
       INNER JOIN #BulkUpdate_Lock_Details t 
          ON p."FileName" = t."FileName";

INSERT INTO Lock_Details ("FileName", LockStatus, UserName, LockTimeStamp)
SELECT t."FileName", t.LockStatus, t.UserName, t.LockTimeStamp
FROM   #BulkUpdate_Lock_Details t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Lock_Details p 
                  WHERE p."FileName" = t."FileName");
END
```

Creating index after having inserted the data give a perfect statistics and a really good execution plan because the only criteria that uses yours ueries is "FileName"

If "FileName" is unique, then add the UNIQUE keyword into the CREATE INDEX command to boost performances a little bit more...

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the update query using a derived table to eliminate the inner join.

```
UPDATE Lock_Details
   SET LockStatus = dT.LockStatus
      ,UserName = dT.UserName
      ,LockTimeStamp = dT.LockTimeStamp
  FROM (
SELECT t.FileName
      ,t.LockStatus
      ,t.UserName
      ,t.LockTimeStamp
  FROM @BulkUpdate_Lock_Details t 
  ) AS dT
 WHERE Lock_Details.FileName = dT.FileName --can use an index on Lock_Details.FileName
```

Should do exactly the same thing, the difference is you're doing a single scan on the @BulkUpdate_Lock_Details table variable.  A single table scan is ok since you need to query every row to select the possible updates anyway; and you can still use an index in the Lock_Details table's [FileName] column to update Lock_Details with index seeks.

The insert query you wrote is fine as long as there is an index on the Lock_Details.[FileName] column.

If you don't have a nonclustered index on the Lock_Details, [FileName] column then you can create one using:

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ncx_Lock_Details_FileName on Lock_Details(FileName);`